# One simple html/css table alignment

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/F8QE5/
I wanted to keep the label 'Password'always in the top portion of the `<td>`. Currently it's going to the middle section of the `<td>`. I will be adding more fields in the right `<td>` dynamically. So always, the label 'Password' should be in the top position. It shouldn't move to the center of `<td>`.

Anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Providing an example on jsFiddle is fine, but please also post the code here on SO.com as jsFiddle might not always be around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `vertical-align: text-top;` in your CSS.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
<td width="150" style="vertical-align:text-top;"> 
   Password:
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td width="150" valign="top">
     Password:
</td>
```

You may check additional information on the same [here at w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.2)